# Rails 4: Need help understanding how to create a form for a joining table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, entity-relationship

After about three days of scouring Stack and other resources for answers. In doing so I have gotten really close but could use some friendly help to get to the finish line. I found an example app to help guide me but it is quite old and I'm not sure what changes were made from Rails 3 to 4.

I created a table to store `user` selected `answers`

```
class CreateResponses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :responses do |t|
      t.references :answer
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :responses, :answer_id
    add_index :responses, :user_id
  end
end
```

Models are set up in the following way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I enter the values using the console it works as intended, so I think I have the relationships defined properly, but I don't know how to do it from in the app itself.

I made the following *unsuccessful* attempt at creating a new `response` record setting the current_id as user_id and answer_id as parameter. I believe my issue stems from a fundamental lack of understanding on my part so please feel free to set me straight:

```
class TakeTestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_take_test, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    params[:response].each do |answer|
      current_user.responses.create :answer_id => answer[:answer_id], :user_id => current_user.id 
    end

    if current_user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @take_test, notice: 'Take test was successfully created.' }
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "There were problems with your test submission."
            render :edit
    end
  end
```

On this `take_tests/new.html.erb` page

```
 <%= form_tag take_tests_path :method => :post do %>

 <ol>
    <% @test.questions.each do |question| %>

     <li><%= h question.content %></li>
     <br>
      <% for answer in question.answers %>
      <ul>
      <li> <%= radio_button_tag "response[answer_id]", "#{answer.id}" %><%= h answer.content %> </li>

      </ul>

     <% end %>
     <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= submit_tag "Submit My Answers" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the User model, add the association:

```
has_many :answers, :through => :responses
```

Then try this in the console, which demonstrates some of the magic of associations: if current_user is an instance of User, then you can add a new Response to join the User to an Answer with something along the lines of:

```
current_user.answers << Answer.find(:answer_id)
```

This should create the response record for you, but also illustrates that you can do such magic as:

```
current_user.answers = Answer.all
```

... or ...

```
current_user.answers = []
```

...or ...

```
current_user.answers = Answer.where( ... blah blah ...)
```

...or ...

```
current_user.answers += Answer.where( ... blah blah ...)
```

Hopefull this helps to get you there!

Comment: Thanks so much David. I will give this a try and let you know.